# l-adic Cohomology groups of the grassmanian G(d, n)

Tags: number-theory, algebraic-geometry, algebraic-topology

I'm trying to evaluate the cohomology groups of the grassmanian, I think $H^{n}(G(d, n), \mathbb{Q}_{l})$ should be trivial for $n$ odd, and that they are $\mathbb{Q}_{l}$ for $n$ even. Is this correct? does anyone know how to show it?

Comment: One can cheat and use the comparison theorems between etale cohomology and betti cohomology to arrive at the answer. I myself have never computed the cohomology in either of the settings of etale or betti cohomology but I think the computation of betti cohomology of the grassmanian is quite classical.

Comment: The Betti numbers of the real/complex Grassmannian are described [here](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Grassmannian#Schubert_cells). Locally, see [here](https://math.stackexchange.com/q/45292/11619). W.C.Kronholm knows what they speak about, yours truly not necessarily so much :-)