# Questions about why a Grassmannian is a CW complex (mainly constructing 0-skeleton structure)

Tags: algebraic-topology

I read up on the following [blog](https://www.mathematicalgemstones.com/uncategorized/the-cw-complex-structure-of-the-grassmannian/), [M. Gillespie's paper](https://www.semanticscholar.org/paper/Variations-on-a-Theme-of-Schubert-Calculus-Gillespie/b89c376f6460344a512694add5816303a58f24f2) and the Hatcher's textbook(K-theory and vector bundle) because why a Grassmannian is a CW-complex. I have some questions about this process. But like a title my question is only restricted to $0$-skeleton (later I will upload subsequent questions about what is an attaching map and how to make $X^2$ strcture and so on...). Also I will focus on $\operatorname{Gr}(4,2)$

- **what is a n-cell structure** : To begin with, anyway , if a Grassmannian is a really CW-complex, clearly the $n$-disk $D_{\alpha}^n$ exists. According to the M. Gillespie's paper, an open  $n$-disk cell is correspondent to the **Schubert cell**, In order to explain what is a Schubert cell, the author explains a **partition**, $\lambda:=(\lambda_1,....,\lambda_n) $ a nonincreasing sequence of nonnegative integers

[image]

Then next, the author explains a **Schubert cell**, denoted by $\Omega_{\lambda}^{o}$, the set of points of $\operatorname{Gr}(n,k)$ whose row echelon matrix has corresponding partition $\lambda$. Next, the author calls the closure of Schubert cell , $\overline{\Omega_{\lambda}^{o}}:=\Omega_{\lambda} $, a **Schubert variety**. Schubert variety is likely correspondent to the closed ball. Frankly speaking, I am not sure why a Schubert cell  analogously plays a role in an open $n$-disk. but I just believe the correspondence. Furthermore, the author explicitly express which element is a Schubert cell and Schubert variety.

**Note**.

> $\Omega_{\lambda}^{o}= \left\{ V \in \operatorname{Gr}(n,k):
>  \operatorname{dim}(V \cap <e_1,...e_r>)=i,  for~ n-k+1-\lambda_{i} \le
>   r \le n-k+1-\lambda_{i+1}  \right\}$
>
> $$\Omega_{\lambda}  = \left\{ V \in \operatorname{Gr}(n,k):
> > \operatorname{dim}(V \cap <e_1,...e_{n-k+i-\lambda_{i}}>)\ge i  \right\}(= \overline{\Omega_{\lambda}^{o}}) $$
> where $e_1=(0,...,0,1), e_2=(0,...,0,1,0)$

- **Constructing $X^{0}$ skeleton** : Then what is a $0$-skeleton? As I said,  I want to construct $ \operatorname{Gr}(4,2)$ and **Example 4.9** on M. Gillespie's paper introduced why $ \operatorname{Gr}(4,2)$ is a CW-complex structure. I cannot imagine which element should become a $0$-skeleton, $X^0$, but the author referred that $\Omega_{((n-k)^k)}$  is a $0$-skeleton. Since in our case, $n=4,k=2$. Thus, $\Omega_{(4)}$ is really a $0$-skeleton. (As I said, I can depend only on the **Note** because I cannot imagine what is $0$-skeleton) In that case, a partition is a single component $\lambda=(4)$  and $\lambda_1 =4$. However,

  $\Omega_{(4)}= \left\{ V \in \operatorname{Gr}(4,2):
   \operatorname{dim}(V \cap <e_1,...e_{4-2+1-4}>)\ge 1  \right\}$ ($n=4,k=2,i=1, \lambda_{1}=4)$
  $= \left\{ V \in \operatorname{Gr}(4,2):
   \operatorname{dim}(V \cap <e_1,...,e_{-1}>)\ge 1  \right\}$ [!]

$\Omega_{(4)}$ is clearly not well-defined. How can we define $e_{-1}$? Or is there  any good suggestion that I understand what is a $0$-skeleton of $\operatorname{Gr}(4,2)$?
,

- **dimension of $X^0$** : Meanwhile, what about the dimension of $0$-skeleton?  clearly and naturally, the dimension should be $0$. In fact, on the given paper, there are following information about the dimension (**Remark 3.8** on the page $9$)

> $(1)$ $\operatorname{dim}(\Omega_{\lambda}^{o})=\operatorname{dim}(\operatorname{Gr}(n,k))-|\lambda|=k(n-k)-|\lambda| 
>  $
> (where $|\lambda|=\sum_{i} \lambda _i $, and we call $|\lambda|$ a
> **size** of partition $\lambda$)
>
> $(2)$ $\operatorname{dim}(\Omega_{\lambda}^{o})=  \operatorname{dim}(\Omega_{\lambda} )
>  $

According to the paper, the dimension is based on a complex number, $\mathbb{C}$, because the author defines Grassmannian on the $k$-dimensional subspaces of  $\mathbb{C}^n$(**Def 3.1** on the page $7$)
hence, more precisely, the above dimension is written as $\operatorname{dim}_{\mathbb{C}}(\Omega_{\lambda}^{o})=k(n-k)-|\lambda| 
$ but I will omit the field $\mathbb{C}$.

Based on the above box on the dimension  and about my interesting Grassmannian, $\operatorname{Gr}(4,2)$, $$\operatorname{dim}(\Omega_{\lambda} )=2(4-2)-4=0$$

But, I think that it seems a very lucky case ; when considering general case, in other words, for any $n,k (k\le n)$ $\Omega_{((n-k)^k)}$ is a $0$-skeleton. In that case, $|\lambda|=(n-k)^k$. Then, in that case,

$$\operatorname{dim}(\Omega_{\lambda} )=k(n-k)-(n-k)^k $$

but, the dimension generally would not be zero.... I cast doubt whether $\Omega_{((n-k)^k)}$ is a $0$-skeleton.

Comment: [A somewhat related thread](https://math.stackexchange.com/a/45305/11619). The links provided by W.C.Kronholm and David Bar Moshe may help you more. I was just counting cells in the given numerical case :-)

Comment: I haven't read your references, but when they write a partition as $((n-k)^k)$, might they not mean $(n-k, n-k, \ldots, n - k)$ (sequence of length $k$)?

Comment: @JHF  That makes sense! I was lack of my sight.